# How to test componentDidUpdate without ending it in a loop

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, single-page-application, enzyme

I want to test componentDidUpdate 
I tried passing {...props} without defining it
it then componentDidUpdate first logs an empty object and then update not required
and this logs them twice and shows props is not defined
How can I test componentDidUpdate without ending into a loop.

My code

```
componentDidUpdate(updateRequired) {
        console.log(this.props);
        if (this.props.updateRequired === true) {
            this.anotherFunc();
        } else {
            console.log("update not required")
        }    
    }
    anotherFunc() {
            this.props.callBackFalse();
    }
```

This is the code I want to test

```
componentDidUpdate(updateRequired) {
        console.log(this.props);
        if (this.props.updateRequired === true) {
            this.anotherFunc();
        } else {
            console.log("update not required")
        }    
    }
```

I tried testing with setProps like this

```
it('checks if component updates on receiving props', async (done) => {
        const callBackFalse= jest.fn();
        let prevProps = {
            updateRequired : false,
            callBackFalse
        }
        let nextProps = {
            updateRequired : true,
            callBackFalse
        }

        const wrapper = shallow(<Feed {...prevProps} />);
        await wrapper.setProps(nextProps); 
        await expect(callBackFalse).toHaveBeenCalledWith(prevProps,nextProps);
        done();
    })
```

and this goes into loop 
(this is how i got to know it went into loop when it prints this code over and over on console)
console.log src/Components/feed/feed.js:12

```
    { updateRequired: true,
      callBackFalse:
       { [Function: mockConstructor]
         _isMockFunction: true,
         (rest of jest mock functions) } }
```

edit:
after changing from shallow to mount

```
it('checks if component updates on receiving props', async (done) => {
        const callBackFalse = jest.fn();
        let prevProps = {
            updateRequired: false,
            callBackFalse
        }
        let nextProps = {
            updateRequired: true,
            callBackFalse
        }
        const wrapper = mount(<Feed {...prevProps} />);
        wrapper.setProps(nextProps);
        done();
        await wrapper.instance.callBackFalse;
        expect(callBackFalse).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
    })
```

now it runs and passed the test but still it keeps on looping and keeps printing on console like this

console.log src/Components/feed/feed.js:12

```
    { updateRequired: true,
      callBackFalse:
       { [Function: mockConstructor]
         _isMockFunction: true,
         (rest of jest mock functions)} }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `componentDidUpdate` you need to compare `prevProps` with current `props` before doing anything that can potentially change the current state of the component, otherwise you might end up having an infinite loop, as you can see on the documentation https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidupdate.

So your code should look like this:

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
  if (prevProps.updateRequired !== this.props.updateRequired) {
    console.log(this.props);
    if (this.props.updateRequired === true) {
        this.anotherFunc();
    } else {
        console.log("update not required")
    }
  }    
}
```